# Backpropagation in a transformer

Tags: python, transformer, pytorch, time-series

I have a transformer for timeseries forcasting based on this article https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.08317

Given a source containing $src=(x_{t-5},x_{t-4},x_{t-3},x_{t-2},x_{t-1})$ and a target of $tgt=(x_{t-1},x_{t},x_{t+1})$, the model then tries to output $out=(x_t,x_{t+1},x_{t+2})$.

When training, I currently provide the model with the $src$ and $tgt$ to produce $out$, which I then compare with real data using the LMSE metric. This approach seems to have limitted success.

However, similar to the NLP tasks, I want to first input $src$ and $tgt=(x_{t-1})$ to the model. Then, I could measure the loss and backpropagate before trying training again on $src$ and $tgt=(x_{t-1},x_{t})$ and continue like this until the model predicts the required length of the output.

Alternatively, I could do the same thing, but backpropagate only in the end.

Which of these strategies is better? Is there an alternative that comes to mind?

Comment: I'd recommend that you put your specific question in the title.